# Correct usage of HTTP VERBS in custom REST implementation

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I have a server-side service (using ASP.NET Core) that should provide a REST API to various clients.

Behind the service, I use a SQL server for data storage.

The controller has the following route attribute:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomDataController : ControllerBase
{…}
```

There are data provider methods:

```
[HttpGet(nameof(GetDataForGuest))]
public async Task<IQueryable<Specs>> GetDataForGuest(int skip, int take, Guid organizationID) => await dataProvider.GetDataAsync<Specs>(skip, take, organizationID);
```

There are methods to create or update data on the server:

```
[HttpPost(nameof(SaveDataToServer))]
public async Task SaveDataToServer([FromBody] List<Specs> specs) => await dataProvider.SaveDataAsync<Specs>(specs, isNewData: true);
```

According to many articles (like [this one](https://medium.com/@suhas_chatekar/why-you-should-use-the-recommended-http-methods-in-your-rest-apis-981359828bf7)), `GET` is for returning some resource, `POST` is for creating and `PUT` is for updating:

> - GET — For returning resources
> - POST — For creating a new resource
> - PUT — For updating a resource
> - PATCH — For updating a resource
> - DELETE — For deleting a resource

However, as you can see, my methods are only facades, the data is saved by the data provider, and I can decide based on a bool variable to insert or update an incoming record.

As you can also guess, I don't use traditional REST URLs (like `api/user/1`), as I need complex data, so my URLs look like this:

```
https://192.168.0.101:8080/api/customdata/GetDataForGuest?skip=0&take=10&organizationID=58b77372-abbc-435e-9a5b-d77bc05129c7
```

Currenty I get data with the `HttpPost` for both inserting new records and updating existing ones (and it works normally). My concerns are about best practice: should I use `HttpPut` when I want to update an existing record?
According to the specifications, using `PUT` is *idempontent* by definition while `POST` is not, so executing the query should not depend on how many times it was called.

On the client side, I use some query building (based on parameters) and I call the method with a `POST` action:

```
public async Task SaveDataToServer(string methodName, List<T> data, bool isNewData)
{
  var parameters = GetParameters(methodName, isNewData);
  var baseUri = new Uri(baseUriString, methodName);
  var targetUri = UriBuilding(baseUri, parameters).AbsoluteUri;
  var result = await httpClient.PostAsync<List<T>>(targetUri, data);
}
```

So using  only `POST` is considered as best practice? Or should I separate the update actions to another method marked with `HttpPut`? Does it matter considering that the logic behind the methods decides what will happen and not the verb?

Comment: are you providing users with a client implementation for your api? if not, why not?

Comment: Yes, I implement a client side as well, and I use Post methods in the HttpClient. I'll add some client side code to the initial question.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to call it REST without following the description of REST.

Comment: @Rob It is not a coincidence that I put this to a question, don't you think? :) I guess it is a custom REST hence the title. Obviously I can't create simple transactions with simple URLs like in some of the demos where I can add a new book and update its title...this is far more complex :)

Comment: Then it's not REST as Dr. Fielding would say to us countless times. You can't create your own version of HTTP and call it REST.

Comment: @Rob Why? Because of the absence of `PUT` or because of the non-traditional URL structure?

Comment: @Nestor because looks like you don't totally understand what REST is. So how can you custom something that is strange to you?

Comment: On the other hand. If we deliberately ignore the HTTP semantics and how they conceal with the so-called REST principles, why to use HTTP at all?  That `httpClient` you use definitively "speak" `HTTP` but you are using it to speak `what-ever-your-protocols-is`. It's like hiring a spanish-speaking to make it speak chinese.

Comment: Strange, that all I can see is why this solution is not REST, yet no suggestion has been made...any. So, can you please focus on how to make it follow best practice without hurting the REST principles?

Comment: @Nestor REST has nothing to do with HTTP methods, parameters and other https things. It's an architectural style. Something that operates at a very high level of abstraction. Your question has nothing to do with REST. It's likely "how to make my API Web compliant". These are 2 different subjects

Comment: @Laiv Thanks for the further clarification. I already know that but my _concrete_ implementation uses HTTP and its verbs and I intend to follow the REST architecture design - currently more or less...

Answer (score 3):

According to this [great tutorial](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restquicktips.html), there are several problems with my initial approach.

- Using [anti-patterns](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html#antipatterns) in the resource naming

> - Good: /users/12345
> - Poor: /api?type=user&id=23

- Using only `GET` and `POST` verbs instead of verbs according to their [respective actions](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html):

> - POST    Create
> - GET Read
> - PUT Update/Replace
> - PATCH   Update/Modify
> - DELETE  Delete

- No status codes to [represent responses](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

So it looks I have to redesign my customized *RESTless* API but following these suggestions, it will be much more REST-like.

Comment: As a matter of fact I was just going to write about the resource naming and at the same time your answer appeared - I see you're on the right track now ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t Nice to see some supporting comment :) Yeah, I guess, it is time to reconsider the phrase: _think before act_… :P

Answer (score 1):

If you provide a client for your api it doesnt matter.

"RESTfullness" implies to most people that you map the different verbs to your operations.

However, as you note its not always the most practical approach and the assigment is somewhat arbitrary.

But the only reason to use the verbs is so that the consumers of the API can create their own clients by following the conventions as they see them.

If you simply provide a prewritten client for the consumers to use, then they will never see the underlying use of the protocol. You can use POST or even DELETE for everything if you like.

Furthermore. the "specifications" for REST are super vague. The idea is that simply by browsing the API a user would be able to figure out the operations. However in practice this isnt really possible. For APIs of any complexity the user will consult and follow the documentation.

At which point you can simply say "for this operation use POST" the user will not be confused, their client will not break, they will just "tsk" if they disagree and type "POST"

Answer (score 1):

> According to many articles (like this one), GET is for returning some resource, POST is for creating and PUT is for updating:

Yes, there are a lot of articles that say that.

There is a consistency problem in that position.  The world wide web depends heavily on HTTP.  The most familiar HTTP clients are web browsers; applications where the primary use case is rendering HTML.  *And HTML only includes native support for `GET` and `POST`.*

So when you ask:

> only POST is considered as best practice?

My answer: it has worked in web browsers for more than 20 years.

If you want to understand what HTTP Methods mean, then you need to read the appropriate specification.  For the "standard" methods, that means [section 4.3 of RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3).  For other methods, you can look them up in the [HTTP method registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml), and follow the links provided there to the authoritative sources.

HTTP methods don't describe what the server *does*, but instead what generic components are allowed to *assume*; they constrain the *semantics* of the requests, not the implementations.

Comment: Shouldn't if be pointed out that it's completely valid to create with `PUT`.  This is such a common misunderstanding i.e. equating the HTTP verbs to CRUD.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use simpler RPC style API instead? Where everything is a `POST`ed as JSON. Some companies have shifted using that instead of REST. Like Dropbox API v2 https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation

Our company also has moved from REST to RPC style APIs and it's awesome.

Edit: In our API binary download is still using `GET` and binary upload is still using normal HTTP form file upload.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here that I think are (common) misunderstandings of HTTP semantics and/or REST.  As noted in answers/comments, REST and HTTP are distinct but the concepts of REST were derived from how the web and HTTP work (and to a much lesser extent, what didn't work so well) so the distinction isn't that important, just something to file away in the back of the mind.

> PUT — For updating a resource

This is probably the most common misconception around HTTP verbs.  Yes, `PUT` can and is used to update resources.  It can also, however, be used to create resources.  The only requirement is that it be idempotent.  In simple terms it's a write.  Whether there was something at a given URI before you do a PUT on it is irrelevant.  The only thing that matters is what it looks like after you do write.  `POST` also creates resources but the distinction it and `PUT` (from a REST perspective) is that with `POST`, the server controls what the URI is for that resource.  With 'PUT' the client controls that.  `POST` is also non-idempotent.  It's a one-shot deal which is why you sometimes get errors in a browser saying that you are attempting to resend a `POST` request.  Essentially that are saying you may be creating a second resource which could be bad if the created resource represents a purchase, for example.  Whether you need `PUT` or `POST` create semantics (or both) depends on your specific needs.

At a basic level, if you need to centralize the control of how URIs get created (e.g. prevent URI collisions between clients) and enforce 'only-once' rules, you should probably be using `POST`.  The other common situation where `POST` is a good fit is when you have a asynchronous requirement.  You have the client issue a `POST` and return the URI where the results will eventually be available.  That way the the client gets an immediate confirmation that the request was received and has a reference it can use for asking the server about that request.  Often resources generated in this way are only available for a fixed period of time.

> As you can also guess, I don't use traditional REST URLs (like api/user/1), as I need complex data, so my URLs look like this: ...

This is another common misconception. REST URIs don't need to look like anything in particular.  A lot of people will argue that a human readable URI is not really RESTful at all.  There are pretty arguments for why that is the case but I would say that it's just not required.  It can be very useful to have human readable URIs but you should not feel constrained.  Whether/when using query params is a good practice is debatable but there's nothing inherently non-RESTful about that.  The semantics of REST can still be followed.  It's more about [expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).